# Terminology for time taken for a program to open

Tags: terminology, software

What do you call the time taken for a software to launch? Let's say a program or an associated file is clicked at t = t<sub>0</sub> and the program loads open at t = t<sub>1</sub>. What is t<sub>1</sub> - t<sub>0</sub> called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is often called **startup time**.

Note there is no "law" or "rule" saying you have to call it this way. If you use just "launch time", for example, I am sure most people will understand what you are talking of. There is no rigidly defined term for everything in IT.